# HASHMAP - threshold and loadfactor & capacity

Tags: java, hashmap

I've always been told that hashmap will resize once the size of map > loadfactor * capacity like what JDK comments says for **threshold**:

[image]

But after reading the source code of HashMap in JDK8, like **put** method:
[image]

The map resize at the time next size > threshold and threshold = the power of capacity instead of capacity*loadfactor for first put opration. Even during resizing, the threshold will be just double of old threshold but not new capacity * loadfactor. 
[image]

Is there any mismatch about the JDK doc? Or maybe i am totally misunderstand. Anyone please help give any suggestions?

Comment: Did you read the constructor

Comment: Yeah. It assigns the power of capacity of parameter to threshold withou loadfactor working with

Answer (score 0):

Because the new capacity is double of old capacity

Comment: Well...I can not see any relationship between double of old capacity with load factor.